# KnpSnappyBundle use image inside response

Tags: symfony

Does anyone know if it is possible to use an image generated with KnpSnappyBundle inside a webpage?
I am able to render an image from html and send it as a response to the client:

```
    $html = $this->renderView('YOPYourOwnPoetBundle:thePoet:poemJPG.html.twig', array(
      'poem'  => $customizedPoem,
    ));

    $data = $this->get('knp_snappy.image')->getOutputFromHtml($html);
```

But I can't seem to find how to use this image inside a html response. How should I use "$data"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might store the image on the filesystem and reference to it as usual.

If you don't want to store the image you can always write a controller which would:

- create a new Response object
- set the content type (to any image content type)
- set the content to contents of $data
- return that response

This way you could generate images on the fly.

Comment: Yes I was looking for a way to generate images on the fly, which is easy to do with an action in a controller that return an image, then load the image like this in the twig file: 
<img src="{{ path('poem_get_jpg') }}" alt="Thumbnail" height="400" width="300" />